# Network error: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to connect to server through Putty. It works fine for few days. Then I entered wrong password few times and Putty is stuck and I force close it. As soon as I do this, I am getting error "Connection timed out" if I try to connect to the site again. I cannot even open my website from home now.

This happened again at friends house today. I am working on my site through Putty all of a sudden putty hangs I force close it. Now I cannot open my website from here nor can I connect through putty.

I dont even know what to search for on google I tried but cant find anything out there on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is it happening on all servers or just that one in particular?

Comment: @SolidSnake859 - What you mean by all servers? I only have one ip i am trying to access through ssh.

Comment: @SolidSnake859 - Yes i can open all websites everything except my website. I cant open that i get connection timed out even if i try to open website through browser now.

Comment: I think you'll find this very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699187/putty-not-connecting-to-server

Comment: @SolidSnake859 - But how will ports affect site from opening in browser?

Comment: Good point. Skip all that port nonsense and try those two steps at the bottom. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25282/discussion-between-solidsnake859-and-noviceme).

Answer (score 1):

Download [zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/) and scan your website for open ports. When you find a few, make sure your router has those ports open using this tool: http://www.portchecktool.com.
Finally, try:
1) Restarting your router, or
2) Downloading [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) to anonymize your traffic and prevent the server from recognizing you...just in case entering your password incorrectly caused you to be blocked from that website.
Hope this helps you!

Comment: Any port number i enter on portchecktool.com it says connection timed out? I tried 22, 25, 1881